Regex for pattern of letters in string
I have a string with several million letters (A to Z, without spaces and line endings).
I am looking for letter patterns of the following type:
X.X.Y.YY
where X and Y stand for any but different letters and "." for any other letters, but not X and Y.
The pattern is a consecutive series of eight letters without "interruptions" by other letter sequences.
For example, "TBTZCFCC" fulfills the conditions of the pattern,
"MSMQTXTT" does too.
But e.g. "TBTZABDCFCC" does not fulfill the condition.
I would like to solve the problem with regex, but I am a layman in this field.
So far I have:
([\s\S])(?!\1)[\s\S]\1([\s\S])

The regex shows me for the following example:
TSPAUTDTRMQVNNSSAVUTAADSHEAOUSVSROTBTZCFCCCPQATITOQOUNGDUPSILS
correct "TBTZCFCC",
but also "TDTR", "SVSR" and "TITO", which only fulfill the first part of the condition.
How do I have to change the regex to find eight consecutive letters that fulfill the condition "X.X.Y.YY" described at the beginning of my post?

What is the regex flavor/library/programming language?

Another one: (.)(?!\1)(.)\1(?!\1)(.)(?!\1|\2|\3)(.)(?!\1|\4).\4\4 - There is not much magic in it, not sure if a case is missed yet!

If your regex engine is .NET and any other that supports unlimited width lookbehind patterns, you can use
(.)(?!\1).\1(?!\1).(?!\1)(.).(?<!\2(?:..){0,2}|\1)\2\2

See the regex demo.
Details:

(.) - X
(?!\1). - any char but the one we have just captured (we'll restrict it further later once we capture Y)
\1 - the X char (the one captured in Group 1)
(?!\1). - any char but the one in Group 1 (to be restricted further)
(?!\1)(.) - an Y (any char but the one captured in Group 1)
.(?<!\2(?:..){0,2}|\1) - any char but the one in Group 1 and Group 2 (not X nor Y), and the (?<!\2(?:..){0,2} lookbehind also validates the previous two occurrences of . in the match)
\2\2 - YY.


You may match the following regular expression, which requires only that the regex engine supports back-references and negative lookaheads.
(.)(?=.{3}(?!\1)(.))(?!\1|\2).\1(?!\1|\2).\2(?!\1|\2).\2\2

Demo
I have assumed the contents of capture group 2 cannot equal the contents of capture group 1. If that is incorrect remove (?!\1).
The expression can be broken down as follows.
(.)        # match a char and save to capture group 1
(?=        # begin positive lookahead
  .{3}     # match three chars
  (?!\1)   # negative lookahead asserts next char does not equal
           # the contents of capture group 1
  (.)      # match a char and save to capture group 2
)          # end positive lookahead 
(?!\1|\2)  # negative lookahead asserts next char is neither the
           # contents of capture group 1 nor capture group 2
.\1        # match any char followed by the contents of capture group 1
(?!\1|\2)  # negative lookahead asserts next char is neither the
           # contents of capture group 1 nor capture group 2
.\2        # match any char followed by the contents of capture group 2
(?!\1|\2)  # negative lookahead asserts next char is neither the
           # contents of capture group 1 nor capture group 2
.\2\2      # match any char followed by 2 instances of the
           # capture group 2


If the regex engine supports subroutines (a.k.a. subexpressions) we can reduce the chance of typing errors by capturing (?!\1|\2). to group 3 and reusing that code twice.
(.)(?=.{3}(?!\1)(.))((?!\1|\2).)\1(?3)\2(?3)\2\2

Demo


I wouldn't bother with a regex.

This could be a linear time algorithm.

We can define what's valid and what's not and run it through your string once in O(N) time. It is easier to maintain and read.


I don't know exactly what's not valid, but generally speaking, it could be as follows:
from collections import defaultdict


def sol(s):
    def is_valid(i):
        """
        X.X.Y.YY is valid
        XAXBYCYY is valid
        XXXBYCYY is not valid?
        """
        for _ in range(8):
            if s[i] != s[i + 2]:
                return False
            if s[i + 6] != s[i + 7]:
                return False
            if s[i + 4] != s[i + 6] or s[i + 4] != s[i + 7]:
                return False
            if s[i + 1] == s[i]:
                return False
            if s[i + 3] == s[i] or s[i + 3] == s[i + 4]:
                return False
        return True

    d = defaultdict(list)
    for j in range(len(s) - 7):
        if is_valid(j):
            match = s[j: j + 7]
            d[match].append(j)

    return sum(len(v) for v in d.values())


print(sol('TBTZCFCC'))
print(sol('TSPAUTDTRMQVNNSSAVUTAADSHEAOUSVSROTBTZCFCCCPQATITOQOUNGDUPSILS'))
print(sol('TSPAUTDTRMQVNNSSAVUTAADSHEAOUSVSROTBTZCFCCCPQATITOQOUNGDUPSILS' * 100000))


For whatever is not valid, you can define a simple if in the is_valid method and eventually return True, if all passed.

This will work only in PCRE but is very mentainable; Try:
(?x)
(?(DEFINE)
  (?P<X>\k<x>)
  (?P<Y>\k<y>)
  (?P<dot>(?!(?P>X))(?!(?P>Y)).)
)

(?P<x>.)
(?P>dot)
(?P>X)
(?P>dot)
(?P<y>(?!(?P>X)).)
(?P>dot)
(?P>Y)
(?P>Y)

See: regex101

Explanation:

(?x): Enable freespacing mode to get a more readable regular expression
(?(DEFINE)...): Define regex subroutines

(?P<X>\k<x>): X should backreference to x
(?P<Y>\k<y>): Y should backreference to y
(?P<dot>(?!(?P>X))(?!(?P>Y)).): dot should be neighter X nor Y


(?P<x>.): x can be any letter
(?P>dot): dot
(?P>X):  X
(?P>dot): dot
(?P<y>(?!(?P>X)).): y can be any letter thats not X
(?P>dot): dot
(?P>Y): Y
(?P>Y): Y


The regex solutions proposed by Cary Swoveland and Wiktor Stribiżew work equally well.
I still need to look more closely at user24714692's idea of a linear time algorithm.
The regex: (.)(?=.{3}(.))(?!\1|\2).\1(?!\1|\2).\2(?!\1|\2).\2\2
by Cary Swoveland in conjunction with Martin Evans' answer to the iteration of a regex in text ( Accessing the contents of a callable iterator object ) produced the results I was hoping for:
import re 

reg = r"(.)(?=.{3}(.))(?!\1|\2).\1(?!\1|\2).\2(?!\1|\2).\2\2"

with open('string.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f_input:
    test = f_input.read()

# Looping over regex matches inside text
for match_num, match in enumerate(re.finditer(reg, test, re.MULTILINE), start=1):
    print(f"Match {match_num} was found at {match.start()}-{match.end()}: {match.group()}")

The string contains 12,986,498 letters; 2,970 letter sequences fulfil the pattern; duration of the calculation: 1.3 seconds.
